# Why is a static file on Azure served slower when served with Node instad of ASP.NET Core?

Tags: node.js, performance, azure, asp.net-core, static-files

(I am unsure whether this is the correct site for this question. If it is, please feel free to remove this disclaimer, otherwise just ping me, I will move and delete it then...)

We are deploying an angular application that has been created using the Angular-CLI toolset to an Azure WebApp. Loading a static file with about 500 KB from a browser takes a good seven seconds in this setup.

When delivering the same file using an ASP.NET Core web application and the `app.UseStaticFiles()` middleware, the load time drops to less than 200 ms.

Am I missing something about Node.js serving static files here? Can anyone point me at what we did wrong here?

Comment: Node's js VM is slower than .NET's CLR compiled code perhaps? Those load times seem really slow, are you sure it isn't network inconsistencies?

Comment: Is this the first time you visit your website? If yes, Azure needs time to warm it up (maybe 10+ seconds). See [windows azure website load time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730557/windows-azure-website-load-time)

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT: No we tried several times, discarding the results of the first time load. Also when using ASP.NET Core sometimes (about one in 20 tries) the load time rises to about 2 to 4 seconds, but mostly is between 150 and 300 ms. We tested this with one WebApp in an S1 and S3 App-Service-Plan.

Comment: @Mardoxx, The network is fine, we tested this both independently from Azure as well as with files delivered by ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Could you share some code snippet of Node.js?

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT I have some difficulties reproducing this issue on a clean WebApp. This is however an angular application generated with the Angular CLI, and a bunch of third party npm packages included, which results in a vendor.js file of about 2 MB, which gets zipped on its way to the browser resulting in a download of around 500 KB.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you don't use IIS to serve static files. IIS has been built in Azure Web Apps.

Comment: Were you comparing the scenario between node.js+Angular and ASP.NET+Angular ? Have you tested the performance individual node.js and ASP.NET server without any frontend framework? Further more, could you kindly provide your code snippets for investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the problem. The app is hosted using IIS and not with Node.js. 
It's the way how IIS transfer and compress the JS files, see the answer here: [Azure Website slow to serve static JS/CSS but not binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373297/azure-website-slow-to-serve-static-js-css-but-not-binary)

We added the following line to `<system.webserver>` in `web.config`

```
<serverRuntime enabled="true"  frequentHitThreshold="1"  frequentHitTimePeriod="00:00:20" />
```

which solved the problem (~8-10 seconds to now ~200 milliseconds).