# Azure websites load takes very long time

Tags: azure, azureportal, page-load-time, load-time

Hello I have recently deployed one of my application on azure portal and it is running fine as well but the issue it takes **15 SECONDS TO LOAD** for the first time when site load.

After site load successfully once than it runs fine but as I open after some interval time of 10 min or 20 min again it takes **15 SECONDS TO LOAD**.

I have read all the documents and applied the same below.

[Performance tips](https://www.azurebarry.com/azure-performance-tips/)

[Traffic Manager Routine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods)

[Azure Advisor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/advisor/advisor-overview)

[Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure)

[Azure Site Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure)

[SOF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730557/windows-azure-website-load-time)

[Azure Resource Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-overview)

[Scheduler](http://fabriccontroller.net/job-scheduling-in-windows-azure/)

I have set **Scheduler** to call my application on 10 minutes of interval time but it is having the same issue as it was.

**The one issue I found is that, it is taking time to locate the server and than give the response so is there any routing mechanism I can provide in azure to locate the server faster? or anything else.**

Comment: Which tier is it running on?

Comment: First load issue is most likely IIS load time, which can be made faster by using Deployment Slots + Application Initialization (set up warm-up routes in web.config).

Comment: @juunas My application is running on (Basic: 1 Small) tier.

Answer (score 6):

Did you turn On the *Always On* knob in Application Settings? —

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#general-settings

> **Always On** —
>
> By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. **In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time.** If your app runs continuous WebJobs or runs WebJobs triggered using a CRON expression, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

Comment: Yes I have already done this as defined in the articles I have posted in my question.

Comment: Collect a .NET profile with Application Insights from the Performance blade. That's going to tell you **what** takes forever to load. Assuming ASP.NET here. Also make sure your `/` route actually warms up the app, since that's what Always On does (a `GET /` request).

Comment: What does this mean - _*it is taking time to locate the server and than give the response so is there any routing mechanism I can provide in azure to locate the server faster*_. Slow DNS resolution? That's a local problem not a cloud problem.

Comment: I have done this as well and it takes 1.5 sec to load the page in result but actually I have to wait at least 15 to 20 sec to load the page.

Comment: @eviSnobu if site has not opened for a while and I try to open the site then at the bottom of the browser, it keeps showing "Waiting for <sitename>" for at least 10-15 seconds. Once the site is located then site opens immediately afterward in couple of seconds time.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem. Any resolution that worked for you @3rules

Comment: @user2185592 Still looking for the solution.

Comment: We are still looking too

Comment: I wanted to turn on Always On to solve this problem but it's dimmed out because I am still on the free plan.  I just found through the article above and skimming through the settings I had my appservice set to .Net Full Framework but I am hosting .Net Core there.  I changed it to .Net Core and it seems to be loading in 4 to 5 seconds the first time instead of 10+ second.  I hope that holds up.  I publish straight from visual studio for my little site and I always wondered what it meant by no matching framework (or to that affect).  I think I just fixed:)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Application Insight configuration in your App Service slot , if you have this activated, it may be affecting the TTFB time (Time to first byte)

It can be an diagnostics listener configured in your Web.config:
https://varioustech.co.uk/?p=20

In case you have the **XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode** configuration key, simply change the configuration from **recommended** to **default**